# When I send a Bluetooth message I can't receive other IR codes

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, infrared

I'm new to Arduino and I don't know how to solve this problem.

I want to send an IR code ''channel'' when Arduino receives one character through Bluetooth or if I send another IR code from a remote.

But if I send the char 'a' through Bluetooth the program doesn't catch any new IR messages.

I am using an HC-06 Bluetooth module connected to pins 12, 13 and an IR receptor connected to pin 2.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <IRremote.h> 

IRsend irsend;
unsigned int channel[67] = { 9300, 4300, 700, 1400, 800, 1350, 800, 1400, 700, 1450, 700, 1450, 750, 1350, 800, 1350, 750, 1400, 750, 400, 750, 350, 800, 300, 800, 300, 800, 350, 750, 350, 750, 400, 700, 400, 750, 1400, 750, 350, 750, 350, 750, 350, 800, 1400, 750, 1400, 750, 350, 750, 400, 700, 350, 800, 1400, 750, 1350, 750, 1450, 750, 300, 800, 350, 800, 1350, 750, 1400, 750};
int RECV_PIN = 2;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;  
SoftwareSerial BT1(12,13);
char incomingChar = 0;

void setup() {
  irrecv.enableIRIn();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  BT1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    int hexen = results.value;
    Serial.println(hexen, HEX);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(hexen, DEC);
    irrecv.resume();
    if(hexen == -16833) {
      Serial.print("Hello");
    }
  }
  if (BT1.available()) {
    incomingChar = BT1.read();
    Serial.print("->: ");
    Serial.println(incomingChar);
    if (incomingChar=='a') {
      Serial.print(" Send ");
      Send();
    }
    if (incomingChar=='s') {
      Serial.print("Test");
    }
  }
}

void Send() {
  irsend.sendRaw(channel,67,38);
  delay(40);
}
```

It's a problem with `irsend.sendRaw`, or maybe some kind of conflict with Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just needed to enable the IR receiver again

```cpp
void Send() {
  irsend.sendRaw(channel,67,38);
  delay(40);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); 
}
```